# How would I go about compiling code via a web app?

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

So I'm looking to develop a online ide for Java with intellisense, but how would I go about producing a compiled class version of the source code?

So essentially I want to click

```
(RUN)
```

then upon clicking '(RUN)' the source code in the textarea to be compiled into a class file and a download link provided for that class.

The inner details/features don't require a explanation, but was just used as an example of what I'm trying to achieve, what I want to know overall is how I could run a Java compiler through a web based app/website

Comment: Upload the string to your backend, put it into a file, compile the file, send the file to the client. (very bad idea btw if you do not know what you are doing).

Comment: @luk2302 of course as I want to avoid malicious code from being executed or the request being elevated

Comment: @luk2302 I'm not just diving right in, I'm aware of potential routes such as using NodeJS or PHP, but was just looking for recommendations.

Comment: The language you use really does not matter all that much since you still need to invoke the java compiler.

Comment: @R2-D2 Your question seems to essentially be asking how to do the hardest and most dangerous part of your entire idea without any specific details

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I just wanted to keep the question simple and not confuse readers with queries about failsafes, preventing elevate requests etc.. Just wanted to know best approach on compiling Java via a web app overall..

Comment: @R2-D2 Questions asking about best practices are generally off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP, get the text from the code parameter, save it to file, and use exec to submit it to javac

```
$submittedCode = $_REQUEST["code"]; //
$myfile = fopen("newfile.java", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $submittedCode);
$res = exec("/usr/local/bin/javac " . $myfile);
if (strlen($res) == 0) {
  //it compiled successfully. load the compiled class file and echo it out. Make sure to set content type header
} else {
  echo $res;
}
```

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton not safe? Can you tell me why? I'm honestly interested to know!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Also I'd be interested if you have a safer solution to the question that was asked

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm not running arbitrary code. I'm running javac on the input. and javac is just to compile java source: I don't know that anything malicious can occur in its execution

Comment: No concrete evidence in this post (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/287606) but the consensus seems to be that you're _probably OK_ if you compile it using a VM.